# How can I sort editor tabs alphabetically and then apply my custom order?

Tags: phpstorm

I have many opened editor tabs. I need to sort them alphabetically but after that apply my custom order on the top of that - basically moving all pined tabs to the "top" (I have editor tabs on the right side).

I know that there is a "sort alphabetically" option when right-click on the editor tabs area and selecting "Sort Tabs by Filename" but after that when I try to make adjustments to the order of the tab it "disables itself" and displaying returns to old unordered list.

How can I apply "Sort Tabs by Filename" and after that apply my custom order for pinned tabs without having to manually adjust order of all tabs ?

Comment: I don't thing you can do this natively inside `phpstorm` but you can use a plugin.

Comment: Currently, there's no such a way. A related feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134996